# Add function overload to existing type in existing node_module

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to add overload declaration to `FormBuilder.group(..)` function from `import { FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";`:

This seems to work:

```
declare module '@angular/forms' {
  interface FormBuilder {
    group<T extends object>(
      controlsConfig: { [key in keyof T]: any; },
      options?: AbstractControlOptions | { [key: string]: any; } | null
    ): FormGroup;
  }
}
```

However, when I add it to my `src\typings.d.ts`, other global type definitions are lost. Entire content of the file is:

```
import { AbstractControlOptions, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

type Public<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };
type Enum<T extends string> = { [K in T]: K};


declare module '@angular/forms' {
  interface FormBuilder {
    group<T extends object>(
      controlsConfig: { [key in keyof T]: any; },
      options?: AbstractControlOptions | { [key: string]: any; } | null
    ): FormGroup;
  }
}
```

I get errors like **Cannot find name 'Enum'.** or Cannot find name 'Public'.

I guess that by using `import` statement, typescript recognizes the file as a ES6 module. How to fix it?